# Sockets can replace HTTP requests? (sockets vs http)

Tags: rest, sockets, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, coding-efficiency

Creating a user, adding some record to collection in the DB, updating some stuff, etc..

All of these we regularly do with HTTP requests against REST api.

Think about making Event bus as server instead of REST api.

In that method, create user will be an event name: "CreateUser" instead of REST api endpoint: POST /users.

In reflect to any action done in the event bus, it will re-emit a following event telling to any body needed to know about, that the event was done.

If for example someone viewing the vehicles collection and another user just edit one of the columns or add a new vehicle instance, it will be reflected immediately to who views it online.

My question is if there attitudes like I mentioned above, if there some formally names for it, if it a good practice, if you know someone who regularly uses it, a framework or something etc. Does the socket.io server can handle and behave like http server in high workloads?

Answer (score 0):

You can use websockets for this; they provide a bidirectional channel between client and server to send messages across. You will have to catch and parse the messages on each end yourself, as there is no additional protocol on top of them.

They don't hold state, so there is no knowledge of who is looking at what, or who got what. You could send the same update message to all connected clients and leave it to the client to use it or not.

You would have to reprogram your client code and the API endpoints, because it's a different way of doing things, and it can also do server push.

I have no idea about frameworks though, as I always use them without one. Websockets are fast, but server behaviour at high workloads depends on implementation, and I only have experience with the websocket server I wrote myself. I suppose the performance of the socket.io can easily be googled.